# Google adword api sandbox url is 404

Tags: google-ads-api

I am trying to implement google adword api and getting "`SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL`"
error, so i checked to access https://adwords-sandbox.google.com but is shows 404 in browser. Any idea about this or this url will work with soap request?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Adwords API sandbox has been [sunset in 2012](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.ch/2012/11/introducing-test-accounts.html). Use [test accounts](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/accounts-overview#test_accounts) instead.